# How do I extract a value from the URL

Tags: java, jsp, url, parameters, uri

I have a URL www.test.com/myshort/myapp/mypage.jsp, where `myshort` is a column value in my database.

I will later query for the id of this shortName (in this example it is 'myshort') which I am doing as

```
select id from mytable where shortName='myshort';
```

How can I extract the 'myshort' value from the entire URL? I can't do `request.getParameter()` since this is not a part of the url parameter. So I am trying to use `request.getURI()`.

Can you please tell me how do I parse and get shortName using `request.getURI()`?

Comment: What's your exact problem? Are you passing your values from page to server through query string?

Comment: I am trying to query results based on the id I will be getting from the shortName from URL. So, if I have to get a variable value from the context root, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand how the data is in your JSP and how do you plan to send it to the server. Without this, I'm not sure if any person could give you an accurate answer.

Comment: I don't have any data in JSP as of now I am trying to learn how to extract the context root value from the url. If you could give me an idea on how exactly do use request.getRequestURI, spilt/parse/substring utilites, that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution/alternative to my issue. I could go ahead and edit web.xml and specify the url format there.

But this is how I solved my issue. I took off the shortName coming from the url and sticked it as URL parameter. this is much more easier to access than what I was thinking earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) framework for this type of server programming.  It gives you the ability to map request patterns with the actual urls and extract such values from the URL.

Comment: That can be done with any MVC web framework (JSF, Struts, Tapestry, Play!, GWT), not just Spring MVC

Comment: I tend to prefer Spring MVC since it is the most non-intrusive framework and has a clean way to structure the code.

Comment: We do not answer based on our preferences, instead of helping OP problem based on what he/she has. Also, Spring MVC could be *the most non-intrusive framework* for you, not for everyone.